# Проблема при работе с JSON в C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

День добрый, проблема с парсингом JSON.
Использую [JSON.NET](http://json.net) для парсинга.

Входные данные:

> {"response":[{"uid":12345,"first_name":"Имя","last_name":"Фамилия","hidden":1}]}

```
var res = Make("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=" + Config.UserId);
//Make делает GET-запрос и возвращает результат. (Верный результат на месте, проверено)
var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
MessageBox.Show(r.response.first_name);
```

На MessageBox.Show() кидает ошибку:

> "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray" не содержит определения для "first_name"

Comment: и это логично - у массива нет свойств, нужно брать свойство конкретного элемента массива, например `r.response[0].first_name`

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чем в косяк!

Comment: @Grundy преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в json - `response` - это массив, соответственно парсится он тоже в массив. А так как у массива нет свойств, нужно брать свойство конкретного элемента массива, например

```
r.response[0].first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

> {"response":[{"uid":12345,"first_name":"Имя","last_name":"Фамилия","hidden":1}]}

Что бы получить response => first_name необходимо использовать код:

```
//правильный вариант
var json = r.response[0].first_name;

//не правильный вариант!
var json = r.response.first_name;
//почему же он не верен? reponse в данном JSON - это массив и мы обращаемся к самому первому элементу, т.е. с индексом 0
```

Comment: лучше пояснять почему именно второй вариант неправильный :-)